# Using Service in HttpInterceptor - Angular2

Tags: angular, service, angular-http-interceptors

I have a Httpinterceptor that starts like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class InterceptedHttp extends Http {

  constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }
```

I would like to use a Service, that I have created and used in many other components. If I add my Service to the constructor, as I would normally do it, I get an Exception. Obivously this is because the constructor cannot differ from the extended class:

> ERROR: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.

Is it still possible to use the Service in my InterceptedHttp Class?

Answer (score 0):

It is no longer recommended to extend `Http`.  If you are using angular 4.3+, you should implement `HttpInterceptor`

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class NoopInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-all-requests-or-responses

Comment: i am not - so what then?

Comment: @ill at this point, there is no reason why you shouldn't be up to date and use the latest.  You can check out this site for the minor changes between releases. https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/